# sendSlash Issue [discord.js-selfbot-v13]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

---

(random string so I can even post this message, please ignore.)

Code:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js-selfbot-v13');
const client = new Client({
    checkUpdate: false,
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
    const channelId = '1190781950944886870';
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  
    if (channel) {
      console.log(`Channel found: ${channel.name}`);
      channel.sendSlash('1190781950944886867', 'about');
    } else {
      console.error('Channel not found.');
    }
  });

client.login('my token');
```

Error:

```
Channel found: general
C:\Users\sir\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\errors\DJSError.js:40
  if (!msg) throw new Error(`An invalid error message key was used: ${key}.`);
                  ^

Error: An invalid error message key was used: botId is not a bot or does not have an application slash command.
    at message (C:\Users\sir\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\errors\DJSError.js:40:19)
    at new DiscordjsError (C:\Users\sir\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\errors\DJSError.js:16:13)
    at TextChannel.sendSlash (C:\Users\sir\node_modules\discord.js-selfbot-v13\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:497:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I were expecting my Account to Trigger the Slash Command `(/about)` of a Bot in the channel by the ID `1190781950944886870`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const { Client} = require('discord.js-selfbot-v13');
const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`);
})

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    

    const channelId = '986457189243838505'; // Replace your channel id here
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  
    if (channel) {
      console.log(`Channel found: ${channel.name}`);
      channel.sendSlash('235148962103951360', 'about'); // Replace your bot id here
    } else {
      console.error('Channel not found.');
    }
});

client.login('token)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).